# final variable not working in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, final

what was i doing wrong ??

I am running Apache tomcat 7 as a service in win 7

my jsp code  [...\webapps\test\index.jsp ]

```
<jsp:useBean id="Counter" scope="session" class="aaa.Counter" />
<html>
<title>sfcsv</title>

<%
    try{
        int x = Counter.read_count(),z = Counter.get_id();
        if(x%2==0)
            out.println(x + " = even");
        else
            out.println(x + " = odd");

        out.println(z);
    }catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
    }
%>


</html>
```

the java code [..\webapps\test\WEB-INF\classes\aaa\Counter.java ]

```
package aaa;

public class Counter {

    private int count;
    private static int instance_counter;
    private final int id;

    public Counter(){
        instance_counter ++;
        id = instance_counter;
        count = 0;
    }

    public int read_count(){
        return count++;
    }

    public int get_id(){
        return id;
    }

}
```

expected output :

```
24 = even    1
```

output that I was getting :

```
24 = even
```

or

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp The method     get_id() is undefined for the type Counter 5: 6: <% 7: try{ 8: int x = Counter.read_count(),z = Counter.get_id(); 9:     if(x%2==0) 10: out.println(x + " = even"); 11: else Stacktrace:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp The method get_id()     is undefined for the type Counter 5: 6: <% 7: try{ 8: int x = Counter.read_count(),z = Counter.get_id(); 9: if(x%2==0)     10: out.println(x + " = even"); 11: else Stacktrace:

description The server encountered an internal error (Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 8 in     the jsp file: /index.jsp The method get_id() is undefined for the type Counter 5: 6: <% 7: try{ 8: int x =     Counter.read_count(),z = Counter.get_id(); 9: if(x%2==0) 10: out.println(x + " = even"); 11: else Stacktrace:) that     prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
The method get_id() is undefined for the type Counter
5: 
6: <%
7:  try{
8:      int x = Counter.read_count(),z = Counter.get_id();
9:      if(x%2==0)
10:             out.println(x + " = even");
11:         else


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
```

**EDIT: On restarting the computer the problem vanished**

Comment: Are you sure the Counter class has been updated in your server webapp?

Comment: I restarted the tomcat server after compiling the java file
what else should i do?

Comment: I tested this and it works fine. Although w/ Tomcat 6 + JDK 1.6. Did you rebuild your war to include get_id()?

Comment: i am totally new o java EE
this is my first jsp code and i didnt bulid a war

Comment: the problem vanished on restating the os

though i still have no idea what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already solved your problem but here are the appropriate options to get all your classes and JSP files to be reloaded or recompiled which might help in understanding what was going on in your case:

**Refreshing Java classes** - Be sure to recompile your classes after applying changes to them. Also see the [`reloadable`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) option for you web application context (default is `false`).

> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected.

---

**Refreshing JSP files** - Please see the [Tomcat Jasper docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) for details on the `development` variable (defaults to `true` so I guess this is its value in your case) and the `modificationTestInterval` variable (defaults to `4 seconds`) with which you may set the interval in which JSP files are checked for changes and compiled if necessary. Both are usually set in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`.

> Is Jasper used in development mode? If true, the frequency at which JSPs are checked for modification may be specified via the modificationTestInterval parameter.true or false, default true.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer.
This instruction is exactly what i was lacking

Answer (score 0):

I think its not problem with your code.I think your IDE is not building your project correctly
ie .class file is not generated properly( or not generated). so try to compile this file manually and place generated .class file to appropriate folder of your project and then build and restart your server.Check on build its building new .JAR file or not

Comment: I am not using an ide  yet in order to gain a betr understanding of the process. But thanks for the reply